# Using exitFullscreenOnClose with fslightbox.js

Tags: javascript, fullscreen

I am happily using fslightbox.js but I can't get it to exit Full screen mode when you press to close it from Fullscreen mode. This means you can get stuck in fullscreen which I don't want as that can be frustrating for people who don't know how to get out of it.

In the documentation at https://fslightbox.com/javascript/documentation/other-props it says I need to use:

fsLightbox.props.exitFullscreenOnClose = true;

but no matter where I position that line of code, it doesn't have the desired effect.

I DO NOT KNOW anything about Javascript, so the answer could be something VERY SIMPLE or it could be just that it does not work for some reason.

I have tried to put fsLightbox.props.exitFullscreenOnClose = true; in the head, in the body, in every place I could think of. I tried adding refreshFsLightbox();

But it still didn't work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I hope this bot is incorrect? Or do I need to show my code?